# Factory method seems to be undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple and straightforward. I've got this factory:

```
ctrls.factory('dataLoad', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        loadFromJSON: loadFromJSON
    }

    function loadFromJSON() {
        $http.get("data.json").then(function(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
}]);
```

This is on the same module than my controller. The controller gets bound to the template after a typical routing technique, but everything gets loaded in the index.html template, so there should be no problems injecting 'dataLoad' in the controller, which works good and gives no errors:

```
ctrls.controller('mainCtrl', ["$scope", "dataLoad", function($scope, dataLoad) {
```

In the controller, I call to the loadFromJSON from a method, and then call that method:

```
function loadData(){
    dataLoad.loadFromJSON().then(function(data) {
        $scope.allCharts = data;
        console.log($scope.allCharts);
    }).then(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
}
loadData();
```

But this, somehow, doesn't work! It gives me the following error:

> Error: dataLoad.loadFromJSON(...) is undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it say when you do console.log(dataLoad) in your controller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loadFromJSON` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined` when you call it.

You probably meant to return the promise that `$http` returns.

```
function loadFromJSON() {
    return $http.get("data.json");
}
```

(I removed the `then` handler you had put there, since it didn't do anything).

Comment: I also think it's most likely that problem :P

Comment: Your example works! I don't know what was wrong with my code tho, I didn't handle the error possibility, but I was going to add it later. What was failing? Why the inner return, after the then statement, didn't work?

Comment: I told you what was wrong. The `loadFromJSON` function had no return statement. So it returned undefined. So when you did: `dataLoad.loadFromJSON().then` you were doing `undefined.then`

Comment: The inner return did work, it just didn't do anything. The return value from a function passed to `then` is ignored.